# Android Navigation Drawer fixed view in Landscape?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

how can i create a responsive Layout for android where i have a Navigation Drawer in portrait mode and 2 columns in landscape mode?

I don't want to use libraries, just basic Android Stuff...

[image: [Here is a picture... i'm not allowed to post them direct]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehqaV.png)

I tried it with Fragments for Navigation and 2 different layouts in 'layout' and 'layout-land'.

**Landscape:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.fun.store.test.ActivityMain">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.fun.store.test.NavigationDrawerFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and **Portrait:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.fun.store.test.ActivityMain">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.fun.store.test.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But it doesn't work because of the Drawer...

Is there any example how to do this?

Comment: why don't you use SlidingPaneLayout instead of drawer layout

Comment: The Drawer should be open by default in landscape?

Comment: Open and not overlapping the content.

Comment: on landscape it will be open and not overlapping the content

Comment: Ok, do you know a good example for SlidingPaneLayout? I never heard about it.

Comment: check the demos for the support library it has a full working example , or you can google it and you will find lots

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133541/navigation-drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation Drawer: set as always opened on tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133541/navigation-drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets)