# Is there any way to set the navigation drawer as visible always

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is there any way to set the navigation drawer as visible always?.

So that the user knows that there is something on the right/left.

Like what you see in Hangouts app.

I know hangouts uses **SlidePaneLayout**, But anyone knows how to achieve this using Navigation Drawer?.

Comment: If you have the navigation drawer always visible, then there would be no more screen space left, I guess the only way this would work is on a tablet and you use 2 fragments, 1 for drawer, then 1 for the content. A good reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133541/navigation-drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets

Comment: NavigationDrawer wasn't meant for this purpose. Either use the SlidingPaneLayout or create your own layout that has the behaviors you want.

Comment: I want a small part of navigation drawer to be visible, like a handle. So that the user will notice it.

Comment: @Karakuri, I tried SlidingPaneLayout , but in closed state it covers the whole window. I need a bit of background to be visible.

Comment: Again, you can create your own layout with the behaviors that you want. Maybe the source code for SlidingPaneLayout will give you some ideas: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.java

Comment: Alternatively, you can have the sliding pane "open" the first time the user uses the app so that they see that it's there, and then you won't need to devote space on a handle.

Comment: @Karakuri, yes i have tried that , In open state i could see tha handle and drag the pane. But when closed it covers the whole window, i still want to see a bit of the background in the closed state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation Drawer: set as always opened on tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133541/navigation-drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got It!!..** Simplicity at its best. No libraries, No complicated codes. Use **SimplePaneLayout**.

Just set the **android:layout_marginLeft** to a suitable value. **:) Awesome :)**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/slidingpanelayout">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="#CCC"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:id="@+id/fragment_firstpane"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="#000"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:id="@+id/fragment_secondpane"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```