# Navigation Drawer for Handhelds, Fragment for Tablets

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

having tried several methods for implementing a Navigation Drawer which is only active on small screen sizes while having its contents always-visible on tablets, I am stuck at the beginning again.

This is what I’ve tried:

- I found approaches [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133541/navigation-drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets) try to make the Navigation Drawer itself always-visible.
- Many solutions use third-party repositories. I wonder why this is the case as Lollipop has the built-in Navigation Drawer.
- The original Android sample for the Nav-Drawer uses methods which are deprecated, like setNavigationMode(). In order to be future-proof, I would like to avoid such things.

**In summary:**
My favorite approach would use the Android Navigation Drawer for small screen sizes and the same content in a fragment for tablets (for redundancy avoidance).
So maybe *one* fragment file. In case of a small screen it is included in a sliding Navigation Drawer and in case of larger screens it is shown directly and always visible at the tablet’s left screen side.

**My question:**
How to make Android include a fragment in a Navigation Drawer if a small screen is present and how to make it included in the root layout for tablets?

Thanks in advance!