# Material Dark Multi-pane layout divider

Tags: android, material-design

**Question**

How to divide list and detail in Material Dark?

Maybe I didn't noticed it before, but when I tried to convert an older multi-pane Holo-Theme app to the new Material-Design, there was no more divider between the `FrameLayout`s on a large screen.

Recently I discovered the trick that's been used on the Light edition (say, the Gmail app): Because the default light background is a little darker than full-white, making the list `FrameLayout`'s background `#FFFFFF` (AND casting a shadow by setting the elevation) creates a great visual divider between the two parts of the screen.

However, I still don't know how to implement this knowledge in a DARK layout, where creating a darker background doesn't seem to be the solution.

Comment: you may try out this pattern https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/layout/adaptive-ui.html#adaptive-ui-patterns

Comment: Your right, it contains a `divide` section. But how to implement it in code so it is divided? Using two `FrameLayout`s results in two screens next to each other but missing a line or something other to indicate it.

Comment: Try out this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133541/navigation-drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets

Comment: Although that post is interresting for if/when i want to add a `DrawerLayout`, this is no solution for my current problem. I've edited my question, maybe it explains it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Awnser

Found it! [This page](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-themes) contains the awnser for the colors of both light and dark (multi-pane) layouts. A quick overview:

**Material Light**

```
List:   "#FFFFFF" (= CardView background)
Detail: "#FAFAFA" (= default background)
```

**Material Dark**

```
List:   "#424242"
Detail: "#303030"
```

I hope this helps others who are trying to implement Material Design in there apps.