# How to add left vertical tab widget in a Fragment

Tags: android

I am working on this POS project for android tablet. I've already created a nav drawer and when I click "Inventory" this page which is a fragment should show.

My question is

(1) how to create vertical tab widget that will show different layout. See picture below.

(2) how to divide the screen that will create vertical line as shown in the same picture.

[image: Inventory]

Comment: Thats Probably a `DraweLayout`but it seems always Open and not even overlay. See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133541/navigation-drawer-set-as-always-opened-on-tablets) . Or i can be wrong maybe its something else (A Simple RecyclerView on left side of window but why Hamburger?) cause i never worked for Tablets .

Comment: Hamburger has nothing to do with the tab widget on the left. When hamburger is clicked, it will show the navigation drawer.

Comment: Ok So you mean There is already a `DrawerLayout` which is closed in this image , Now i think this is just a `RecyclerView` of items in a `Fragment` .

Comment: Yes, there is already a DrawerLayout. Ok, will try that. Thanks!